# Как сделать такой текст в TextView android

Tags: java, android, ui, style, design

[image: Табло]

Как сделать такие цифры как на скриншоте ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152010/5330439

Comment: @TimurVI Огромное спасибо !